# How to Configure Angular 2

Tags: angular

Trying to configure Angular 2 as per Angular 2 document and available resources but getting stuck. So how to Configure Angular 2 environment in Visual studio or any native editor.

Comment: Why not use angular cli. It will save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Install visual studio editor and add this plugins

[image]

And also [TypeScript Emmet](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jakethashi.vscode-angular2-emmet) as commented by @Sasxa

This is all you will need for development.

Comment: You forgot [TypeScript Emmet](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jakethashi.vscode-angular2-emmet) :)

Comment: Thanks for that @Sasxa.